# How to change the brightness of the screen permanently?

Tags: android, service, brightness, screen-brightness

I've been having a lot of problem making an app to reduce the brightness of the screen of my android mobile below the normal levels for a project. I've done a lot of research and have made a program. The program does reduce the brightness of the mobile, but it does not keep the change as the activity is lost when it shuts down. I want to keep the activity alive in the background. I know I must use the service, but I'm unable to implement it. So, my program is :

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.provider.Settings.SettingNotFoundException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private SeekBar seekBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        seekBar.setMax(200);

        float curBrightnessValue = 0;
        try {
            curBrightnessValue = android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(
                    getContentResolver(),
                    android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
        } catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int screen_brightness = (int) curBrightnessValue;
        seekBar.setProgress(screen_brightness);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            int progress = 0;

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progresValue,
                                          boolean fromUser) {
                progress = progresValue;
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // Do something here,
                // if you want to do anything at the start of
                // touching the seekbar
            }



            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
                        String.valueOf(Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL),progress);
                android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL);
                WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutpars = getWindow().getAttributes();
                layoutpars.screenBrightness = progress / (float)255;
                layoutpars.alpha=0.05f;
                Window window = getWindow();
                window.setAttributes(layoutpars);
                //window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
                window.setDimAmount((float) 1.0) ;
                window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Can anybody help me out on this one? If you find this question a repetition of some previously asked question, kindly put the link to that question too. While suggesting how to implement services in this, please tell the exact position where I have to add that/those line(s) of code. Thanks in advance.

PS: I'm quite a noob, and I find it better to understand by programming rather than reading what's in the textbooks. So, if you find something that is very foolish in the program, please don't be judgmental.

Comment: Service would be the way to go to make sure it works on background. What are your roadblocks for using a Service instead?

Comment: The tutorials available only allow me to use service using a second class. Now, I don't really know what to put in the other class. I know that I have to put the putInt() part somewhere in the service for it to stay, but I just can't put a finger as to where exactly should I. And my teachers are also not very helpful in it :/

Comment: Basically you would need a very simple Activity to launch your Service by calling startService(). Then mostly move all your code to the Service. Should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: I'm really sorry but I'm unable to understand how to carry the process out. I tried to move code to Service, but much of my code requires elements from Activity class, and I can't implement it since I'm already extending Service class. Could you help me out, like maybe edit the code or tell me what to put where exactly?

Comment: Moreover, I've noticed that maybe because I'm using the window, the top status bar, which shows time and notifications, shows no signs of any change in brightness. Is there a way I could change that? I'm trying to make the app much like any other screen filter apps(ex: Bluelight Filter).

Comment: You are right. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565054/android-development-changing-screen-brightness-in-service